# I am trying to make button disappear after clicking it in tkinter but its showing error like nonetype object has no attribute pack_forget()

Tags: python, tkinter

##importing tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
```

###function to destroy button

```
def hide():
       b.pack_forget()
       l=Label(r,text="destryed").pack()
```

##main body

```
r=Tk()
r.geometry("1000x1000")


b=Button(r,text="click",command=hide()).pack()



r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `b=Button(r,text="click",command=hide()).pack()` is highly discouraged. The reason is that whatever .pack() returns (always  a None type) will be stored in P1 and not the Button object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the definition of `b`. If you want `b` to be the button, you can't pack it on the same line.

The `pack()` method will always return `None` as there is no return. So, you define your variable `b` as `None`. Instead, first define the button and then pack it:

```
b=Button(r,text="click",command=hide())
b.pack()
```

So, the button is stored in variable `b` and you can destroy it.

Comment: It should be `command=hide`.

Comment: Thanx a lot sir it worked!!!!!